# How to notify data change to the Fragment class?

Tags: java, android

I want to re-bind the Fragment with the Horizontal Recycler view when I hit a button in the ProductDisplay activity. The problem is, when I remove and add the fragment again (or detach and attach), the fragment doesn't reset since all the data created in the Fragment class in the first place.

Fragment class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_category_list, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new HorizontalCategoryAdapter(ProductDisplay.cContent.getCategoryList(), mListener));
    }
    return view;
}
```

When I remove the fragment, and add it again in the MainActivity my previous selections remains the same even though I run this command:

```
if(frag instanceof HorizontalCategoryItem){
                        cContent.resetFilters();
                    }
```

in which I just run:

```
 public void resetFilters() {
        for(Category c : categoryList){
            c.setSelected(false);
        }
    }
```

Interestingly, when I remove and add another fragment, then add this one again, my selections are reset. So, very complicated situation to explain but I tried my best. I want some way of re-binding the fragment or calling a notifyDataChanged type of command inside a fragment. Any ideas?

Comment: what is your " remove the fragment" means.Please show the code

Comment: ```FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.remove(frag);                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer,sbf,"distanceFragment");```

Comment: did you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: Nope, I couldn't find the method to overwrite the notifyDataSetChanged() function in the class that extends the fragment

Comment: Please show the whole fragment file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions:

1. change the datasource for HorizontalCategoryAdapter and **.notifyDataSetChanged()**
2. **delete** the fragment from memory and recreate it again
3. move setAdapter from *onCreateVew* into *onAttach*